# Rails extending models without modifying the base file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got two Rails 2.3 applications, we'll call them **admin** and **frontend**. In **admin** I have all my models specified in `app/models`. In **frontend** I have those models symlinked. I would like to add **frontend** specific methods to a model that only show up for the **frontend** application, and not the **admin** app.

At first I tried just adding `config.autoload_paths += "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/augments/address.rb"` with:

```
class Address
  def hello
    "hello world"
  end
end
```

But that just wasn't loaded. Calls to `Address.first.hello` would be met with `undefined method 'hello'`.

If I require a file that does this:

```
Address.class_eval do
  def hello
    "hello world"
  end
end
```

It is loaded once, and for the first hit in development it works, but all subsequent reloads it fails. This is due to `config.cache_classes = false` in development.

A semi-working solution is to run that from ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  Address.class_eval do
    def hello
      "hello world"
    end
  end
end
```

Which does reload and works every time in dev andprod, but doesn't work for script/runner or script/console. (If this is the only solution I'm sure we could extract that out into a module and `include ModelExtensions` in ApplicationController.)

Is there something I can add to environment.rb or an initializer that will get reloaded every time in development?

Answer (score 0):

To extend your class you should use **module** and include it in your model. Something like this:

```
module  Address
  def hello
    "hello world"
  end
end
```

This is an old but always interesing article on that argument: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/1/17/concerns-in-activerecord

To include the module only in frontend you should check if the module exists with:

```
Class A
  include Address if defined? Address
end
```

Comment: Yea, but I don't want to actually add **include AddressModelExtensions** to my address.rb, because that wouldn't work for my **admin** app, since the module only lives in **frontend**

Comment: mmm... yes I got it. Just a question, why you should use two different apps?

Comment: Code separation and loading. Plus they'll show up separately in NewRelic and we can potentially scale them separately.

Comment: Maybe you need to search a conditional include in your model. Something like **include Address unless Address.nil?**. I know that it doesn't work... but something similar

Comment: You can check the updated answer. I added **defined?** and now should work.